# Autoupdating an excel table in a word document

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

Not really a microsoft/windows user so apologies if the answer is obvious. I am running a windows 7 machine using `microsoft office 2007`. I have an excel spreadsheet in which a series of different measurements are made each day. Within the spreadsheet there is a table highlighting the range of each measurement based on mean +/- standard deviation from the last months measurement.

```
Isotope Range       
Cs-137  7.52    -   7.70
In-111  5.93    -   5.99
I-123   6.36    -   6.45
I-131   9.68    -   9.81
99mTc   13.75   -   14.07
```

There will be a slow decay in each measurement over time and the range for each isotope will slowly drift over time. I would like to link this table into a microsoft word document so that whenever new values are added to the spreadsheet and a range changes that these changes will translate through to the word document. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple; you open both the Excel and the Word documents, and then simply copy the relevant table area in Excel (select and press CTRL+C), and paste it in word at the desired location *as a link* (in the Home ribbon, click on the arrow under Paste, and select one of the two 'Link...'):

[image]

It can be refreshed in Word with F9, and will update each time Word is opened.

Comment: Hi this doesn't seem to work for me neither with F9 or when word is opened

Comment: sorry, seems it is _not_ the default, that was my setting only. I have updated the instructions.

Comment: I was about to install this tool to do that https://analysisplace.com/Document-Automation/Get-Started.  I don't know what is the difference.